# How do I add a job to Jobber docker image?

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a Docker container that exclusively runs the official Jobber job scheduling tool. It comes loaded with an example script that just prints a statement every second. Great. The help menu and documentation don't suggest how I would actually add my own job here. I want to add a script that runs a container that executes a python script.

This is the current `.jobber` list of jobs that I can see once I enter the bash for the container:

```
~ $ cat .jobber
[jobs]
- name: ExampleJob
  cmd: echo "Jobber is running!"
  time: '*'
```

How can I add my own? I am using `docker-compose` to build this container and override the entrypoint to execute my own command (example below), but then it executes it and stops the container runtime:

```
  jobber:
    image: jobber
    entrypoint: /bin/sh/home/jobberuser -c "
      echo The donkey is in charge;"
```

The above command is just a test to override the entry point. Ultimately, the job will be running a Dockerfile that runs a script:

```
FROM python:3.8.2-slim
WORKDIR /src
RUN pip install --upgrade -v pip \
        lxml \
        requests \
        beautifulsoup4
COPY ./scrape.py .
RUN mkdir -p /src/output
CMD scrape.py
```

Comment: If the job configuration is just a text file like that, can you use `volumes:` to bind-mount a configuration file from the host over the file in the image?  How was the image originally built?

Comment: @DavidMaze this image is built via `docker-compose`. The second code snippet here reflects that. The job is actually supposed to be running another docker container that contains a script. So essentially, this job should run a Dockerfile--I added the contents of that Dockerfile above.